# Span sideways figure over multiple pages

Tags: floats, page-breaking, subfloats, rotating

I have to place two `sidewaysfigure` spanned each one on different pages.

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
 \ContinuedFloat
 \centering
 \subfloat[Change in ABC]{\label{fig:abc}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{./abc.png}}
 \quad
 \subfloat[Change in DEF]{\label{fig:def}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{./def.png}}
 \caption{Change in ABC and DEF}
 \label{fig:abcdef}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

But, when I use the above code, (or even when I change `\quad` to `\clearpage`) the figures appears in the same page.

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47645/twopagepicture-package-refining. If this is what you are after please post some more details on figure sizes etc... and will try and assist you.

Comment: Thanks. However, this is not the problem. The two figures are graphs of dimension 1024x768. Each graph should spread a whole page in order to get enough information to analyze. But, these two figures have to be plotted as subfigures. I hope this would be enough.

Comment: Please consider providing a full MWE (minimum working example) that produces the unwanted outcome you're trying to address. Which LaTeX packages are you loading, and what are the paper and the textblock sizes? Incidentally, because you insert a `\quad` rather than a paragraph break, LaTeX will definitely try to place the two subfloats side by side.

Comment: I am using texlive in FC13 (kpathsea version 3.5.6). Instead of \quad i have tried \qquad, \pagebreak, \newpage etc. In the outcome, both the figures appears on a page with second half of the first pic and first half of the second pic. If I use \quad, they appear side by side (with only a little portion visible from the second pic).

Comment: Simply use two `sidewaysfigure` environments here!?

Comment: It has to be floated as subfigure. It needs to be entered in list of figures.

Comment: I believe this question was answered here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right

Comment: @Steve No. The figures are TWO SEPARATE graphs, NOT a single huge figure, to be plotted over two pages as two SUBFIGURES.

Comment: Use \subcaptionbox as link below.

see [link][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161070/numbers-keep-continuing-problem-with-subfig-and-continuedfloat

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using `\ContinuedFloat` the wrong way. It is supposed to be used in the second of two `figure` environments, both of which contain `\subfloat`s. See the example in section **2.2.3 The `\ContinuedFloat` Command** of the [`subfig`manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subfig).

A possible solution using `sidewaysfigure` would then be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[lofdepth]{subfig}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}  % to create dummy text
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\kant[1-3] 
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
 \subfloat[Change in ABC]{\label{fig:abc}\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
 \caption{Change in ABC and DEF\label{fig:abcdef}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
 \ContinuedFloat
 \centering
 \subfloat[Change in DEF]{\label{fig:def}\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
 % \caption[]{Change in ABC and DEF} % Not necessary
  % optional argument empty to suppress duplicate entry in LoF
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\kant[4-5]
\end{document}
```

You must have a `\caption` in the first float/`sidewaysfigure`, but in the second (and any subsequent figures) it is not required. If you do include a `\caption` in these, add an empty optional argument, else the main figure is listed multiple times in the LoF.