# Numbers keep continuing - Problem with subfig and ContinuedFloat

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I have a problem with the numbering in continued subfloats. I just changed my package (subfigure) to subfig because I read that this allows me to continue subfloats on a new page using the command `\ContinuedFloat`.

However, now I have the problem that the numbering (actually lettering) of subfloats continues, even if I close the figure environment and make a new one (containing subfloats) - see screenshot attached.

This problem happens more than once, but here is an example of code.

**edit**: I have narrowed it down: every time I use `\ContinuedFloat` the next normal figure environment will *also* be a continuation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]   \centering
\subfloat[Sommer während Schwall -- Überblick]
{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{HEM_suitability-index.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/SOM/WUA_Asw.png}}
        \caption{Habitatverteilung für den Istzustand im Sommer (Bachforelle) -- Übersicht}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]   \centering
       \ContinuedFloat 
\subfloat[Sommer während Schwall -- Detail 1 \label{dr:s:ist:d1}]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/SOM/WUA_D1sw.png}}
\subfloat[Sommer w. Schwall -- Detail 2]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/SOM/WUA_D2sw.png}}

\subfloat[Sommer w. Sunk -- Detail 1]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/SOM/WUA_D1su.png}}
\subfloat[Sommer w. Sunk -- Detail 2]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/SOM/WUA_D2su.png}}
        \caption{Habitatverteilung für den Istzustand im Sommer (Bachforelle)}
        \label{dr:s:ist:som}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]   \centering
         %--- NOT CONTINUEDFLOAT - but it does continue with the letters ---
\subfloat[Winter während Schwall -- Detail 1]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/WIN/WUA_D1sw.png}}
\subfloat[Winter w. Schwall -- Detail 2]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/WIN/WUA_D2sw.png}}

\subfloat[Winter w. Sunk -- Detail 1]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/WIN/WUA_D1su.png}}
\subfloat[Winter w. Sunk -- Detail 2 \label{dr:w:ist:d2}]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Drau2/Salmo/ist/WIN/WUA_D2su.png}}
        \caption{Habitatverteilung für den Istzustand im Winter (Bachforelle) }
        \label{dr:s:ist:win}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have been using `\phantomcaption` for when I don't need to display the first caption. That causes no problems in the further numbering.

Help would be much appreciated because I am totally losing my nerves with subfigures.
- Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've used \usepackage{graphicx} without float, it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Switch to the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package.

#### Long answer:

The problem comes from a bad interaction between the  `H` placement specifier from the `float` package and `subfig`, as the following reduced example shows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image1}}\quad
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image2}}
\caption{First part of a continued float}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\ContinuedFloat 
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image3}}\quad
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image4}}
\caption{Second part of the continued float}
\label{dr:s:ist:som}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image5}}\quad
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image6}}
\caption{Another independent figure with subfigures}
\label{dr:s:ist:win}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Removing the `H` placement specifier fixes the problem with the subfigures, but creates another one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image1}}\quad
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image2}}
\caption{First part of a continued float}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\ContinuedFloat 
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image3}}\quad
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image4}}
\caption{Second part of the continued float}
\label{dr:s:ist:som}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image5}}\quad
\subfloat[test]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image6}}
\caption{Another independent figure with subfigures}
\label{dr:s:ist:win}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, the subfigures are correctly numbered, but figures are not. The definitive solution is to switch to the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package (you can even use again the `H` specifier). In the following example I used `\subcaptionbox`, but the package offers also a `subfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{test}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image1}}\quad
\subcaptionbox{test}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image2}}
\caption{First part of a continued float}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\ContinuedFloat 
\subcaptionbox{test}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image3}}\quad
\subcaptionbox{test}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image4}}
\caption{Second part of the continued float}
\label{dr:s:ist:som}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{test}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image5}}\quad
\subcaptionbox{test}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image6}}
\caption{Another independent figure with subfigures}
\label{dr:s:ist:win}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Does the bad interaction always happen? I think it did not happen in all my documents where there are a few `subfigure` environments. So I am wondering, thanks!