# Overcoming interaction with H specifier while staying on subfig package

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats, subcaption

I know that from the `float` package and `subfig` you get a bad interaction with an H specifier. (see: [Numbers keep continuing - Problem with subfig and ContinuedFloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161070/numbers-keep-continuing-problem-with-subfig-and-continuedfloat/379897#379897))

I tried to just add subcaption package to correct this problem, however i get an error saying:

***LaTeX Error: No counter 'subfigure@save' defined
.***

Now the problem is that my thesis has been already written, and only one figure that runs over 3 pages needs numbering correction due to this issue (it starts with 3.14 and ends with 3.12 as you flip pages, however it needs everywhere to say 3.12). 
Throughout my thesis all my remaining subfigures are correctly numbered.
Unfortunately, it is too much work and I do not have enough time to replace all my subfigs to subcaptions package.

Now two questions:

- is there a way to make these two packages work (`subfig` and `subcaption`)?

If not...

- Is there a way to force this figure that continues over 3 pages (while using `subfig` package) to have the ***same figure number*** in each page?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: From the first page of the documentation of `subcaption`:  `Please note: This package is incompatible with the subfigure and subfig packages. `

Comment: Yes i am aware, but i am looking for solutions.