# How to put figures in continuous manner

Tags: two-column, subfig

I have a double column tex file, I wanted to put to figures in continuous figures. But I am getting gaps. How to fill these gaps with my figure. If it won't fit, try to put in another page. but should hold a common caption for al figure. how to do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \twocolumn
  \section{Haha}
  \lipsum[1-5]

  \begin{figure}[!htb]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=0.25\textheight}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
          \caption{Mode 1}
          \label{fig:trans surface mode 1}
    \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
          \caption{Mode 2}
          \label{fig:trans surface mode 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
          \caption{Mode 3 }
          \label{fig:trans surface mode 3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
         \caption{Mode 4 }
         \label{fig:trans surface mode 4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: A `figure` is not automatically broken in pages. You will have to do it and use a `continuation` caption.

Comment: Some examples in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161076/1952

Comment: You could use `\end{subfigure}
    \caption{your caption for all 4 images}
     \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}
   \ContinuedFloat` instead of  the `\end{subfigure}` command of your second image. This way, the first two images can be placed on the first page while the third and fourth image are placed at the second page. Numbering of the images will stay continuous from a to d.