# Image spread over 2 pages

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, photobook

I'm publishing a photo book. Chapters consist of groups of photographs, no text, and some images are spreads over 2 pages. I found this solution: [\twopagepicture package refining](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47645/twopagepicture-package-refining)

It works fine but the images are not in a figure environment, so I cannot generate a list of figures... Is there a way that my 2 page images also appear in my list of figures with their caption and are numbered together with the standard pictures, that are in the figure environment?

Comment: You can use `\captionof{figure}{...}` outside a figure environment (caption or capt-of packages).  It is standard in KOMA script.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this without KOMA script classes? I use the octavo package document classes and I already invested in it --- this is the third volume of a series and the only one that contains photos. Also: I'm a beginner latex user and not familiar at all with Koma...

Comment: Most people use the caption package, although capt-of has fewer side effects..  I do not in any way advise using KOMA, but if you were already using it...

Comment: Understood. It works with the caption package.  Thanks!